# Difficulty with configuring paths before compiling

Tags: osx, libraries, configure

I'm running MacOS Mojave 10.14.2 with Homebrew and MacPorts installed; I'm attempting to install the dsniff suite via the command line, and I installed Xcode's command line tools for this purpose--I also have Xcode 10.1.

Whenever I run `sudo port` and `install dsniff`, I get in return:

> Error: Failed to configure dsniff, consult /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_net_dsniff/dsniff/work/dsniff-2.4/config.log
>   Error: Failed to configure dsniff: configure failure: command execution failed
>   Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_net_dsniff/dsniff/main.log for details.
>   Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
>   Error: Processing of port dsniff failed

- First error log: https://pastebin.com/pFjr0wLJ
- Second error log: https://pastebin.com/jBjFSBvy

I get the same error messages when running `install dsniff -devel` as well.

After having read around online for solutions and interpreting the log provided, I tried the installation with Brew.

I ran `brew install berkeley-db libnet libnids libpcap openssl` and all of the dependencies were either updated or installed. The primary problem I'm encountering is in attempting to configure the paths for the dependencies.

Whenever I try to run `./configure /`followed by the configure script, I get $ ./configure: No such file or directory:

```
--with-libpcap=/usr/local/opt/libpcap \

--with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl \

--with-libnet=/usr/local/opt/libnet \

 --with-libnids=/usr/local/opt/libnids \

 --without-x
```

I'm at a loss for how to proceed.

Comment: Afaik dsniff scripts and code base are too old. I have not been able to compile it either. It should be removed from macports.